# How to convert minutes into (YY MM DD HH:mm:ss) in excel?

Tags: excel, type-conversion, converters

I'm using manipulating time in excel.
I have the date in minutes I want to convert it into the format.
`YY MM DD HH mm`  
where:

```
mm:Minutes
HH:Hours
DD:Days
MM:month
YY: year
```

Im using the following logic:
For  124 minutes I have

```
124/60= 2 hours
124%60 = 4 minutes
```

and so on for the days and the months and the years

The units Im using are:

```
mm-> HH /24
HH-> MM /30
MM-> YY /12
```

But something is really wrong:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what was happening?
Thanks a lot, guys

Comment: You cannot meaningfully represent a date "in minutes" without telling us what your epoch is. e.g. for "21 minutes" what should the year, month, and day values be?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are "really wrong" because in real life, months have anywhere between 28 and 31 days, so you cannot represent a large number of minutes as a "date" that uses variable measures for years and months.

On the assumption that as units of measure you want to use ...

- Year = 360 days
- month - 30 days

... you can calculate as follows:

[image]

That's also what your calculation shows. If something is "really wrong" with that, it's probably your expectation, which is based on the traditional 365.25 day year.

Maybe you want to edit your question and explain what you expect as the "really correct" result.

Comment: Following your example, and to get the remaining minutes I'm using the `= INT(MOD(B1,60))` formula, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel dates are fractional number of days from 31-Dec-1899 (date 0 is formatted as 0/1/1900). So why don't you just add your minutes (after dividing by (24*60) to convert to days) to the earliest valid date in EXCEL (1900-01-01) and use the TEXT function to format:
=DATEVALUE("1900-01-01")+(**21**/24/60)-1
The bold part is your minutes.
This is now a proper EXCEL date; you can use TEXT function to format it into any way you like, or you can use DAY(), HOUR(), etc. functions to extract parts.

Having said that I don't know what your minutes represent; What date does **Full Time in Minutes:21** correspond to?

Comment: The OP specifies that a month = 30 days. So your DateValue won't work, since it uses the real month days, which range from 28 to 31.